# Fields missing from Crystal Reports SQL file when setting database links

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am creating a report in Crystal reports from a set of SQL database tables I have two tables that are to be linked, when I select the two tables and then go to set the links, the field that I need to select for the link in one of the tables is missing from the list of fields in the database expert links tab.  Upon further inspection a number of fields are missing, there doesn't seem to be any specific field type or order or reason to why these fields are missing.  I also found if I just use that one single table to create a report, all fields show in the field explorer. Also if I use the two tables and select a different available field to link the tables, all of the fields show in the field explorer.  So all the fields are there and contain data and work correctly however when in the database expert, Links tab, a number of fields do not display in the one table.  I have created probably over 1000 different reports and used many combinations of tables (just not this particular table) and have never seen this problem.  This table has about 120 fields (which is larger than most that I use) and only 80 of those fields show in the database expert links tab. I am using Crystal Reports  11.5.8.826, SQL Server2008 R2. I have tried starting over, rebooting, etc..  Thinking it may be some sort of limitation to how many fields are listed in the links tab?

Answer (score 1):

Appears that the missing fields were Text fields.  Had to change the data type in SQL to varchar.  Not sure why, but Crystal Reports doesn't allow text fields for SQL for file links.